# Media queries not working with Safari

Tags: safari, media-queries

Why does the following media query work fine in FF (22.0) and Chrome (28.0.1500.71), but Safari (6.0.5) ignores it?

In case it's relevant, I'm using Mac OS X (10.7.5) macbook pro 13"

Thank you for your help!

Also, does anyone know if it works in IE?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>title</title>
<style type="text/css">

body {background-color:#efefef;}
h1 {color:black;}

@media only screen and (max-width:37.5em) {
body {background-color:#000000;}
h1 {color:white;}
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Hi.</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why it wasn't working:

To test the media query, I was zooming in on the page, rather than resizing the browser window, and in Safari, unlike FF and Chrome, the media query doesn't kick in until you've refreshed the browser.